# Jquery Delay for on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hi I have set of icons that I want to display one by one when it scroll down.

I used http://www.justinaguilar.com/animations/ for the animations.

How can I add the delay function on my jquery so it will be visible one by one?
Any plugins that can alternate this kind of effect?

Any suggestions?

Thanks guys

[image]

html code

```
     <div id="create" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">
                    <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <i class="fa fa-user fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                    <h4>Create an account</h4>
                </div>

                <div id="define" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">

                    <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                    <h4>Define your API</h4>

                </div>

                <div id="sync" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">

                    <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                    <h4>Sync the local client</h4>

                </div>

                <div id="cloud" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20" >

                    <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <i class="fa fa-cloud fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                    <h4>Get data from the cloud</h4>

                </div>

                <div id="scale" class="col-lg-15 col-md-15 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 ac m-t20 m-b20">

                    <img src="//placehold.it/80x80" alt="folder" class="img-circle">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <i class="fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-5x m-t10"></i>
                    <h4>Scale as required</h4>

                </div>
```

css code

```
#create, #define, #sync, #cloud, #scale
{
  visibility:hidden;
}
```

jquery code

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#kinect-logo').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("slideUp");
        }
    });
    $('#create').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).delay(300).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });
    $('#define').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });

    $('#sync').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });

    $('#cloud').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn");
        }
    });

    $('#scale').each(function () {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).addClass("fadeIn").delay(300);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $('#kinect-logo,#create,#define,#sync,#cloud,#scale').each(function (index,element) {
        var imagePos = $(this).offset().top;
        var topOfWindow = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (imagePos < topOfWindow + 400) {
            $(this).delay(index*600).queue(function(){
                $(this).addClass("slideUp").dequeue();
            });
        }
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hEuC3/

http://jsfiddle.net/hEuC3/1/

Comment: WOW! thank youuuuu! I implement it on my site it works perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You can add a delay using the java script function setTimeOut()

```
setTimeout(function (){
// Code you want to delay or you can call the function reference directly instead of defining one
}, 2000);
```